# What screw is missing from this carb (photos included)

Tags: carburetor, part-identification

I'm repairing a carb and the part (screw?) which goes in here broke, and I'm struggling to find a replacement as I'm not sure what to search for! What's it called?

[image: opening hole on outside of carb]

As shown in the picture it's a round entrance but then goes into a smaller rectangle hole.

It's purpose is to poke out inside of the throttle tube and keep the throttle plastic riser part straight. Otherwise the throttle riser doesn't go down as it's blocked by the idle screw. I'm guessing based on the shape of the hole that the part which sticks out is rectangular.

[image: hole on inside of the carb]

All that's written on the carb is a TK logo, and F28-720000-11-W1401 5A05 1. It's off a 2015 Sinnis SP125 motorcycle, otherwise known as a Sinnis JS 125-7F.

Comment: If you included the exact model of carb you're working with, someone would be in a lot better position to help you.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I've edited the question and added all I know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered a replacement carb instead. Nothing else I could do.

Comment: Yep, sometimes that's your only good choice.